# Adding Textbox value into concatenated formula

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I was hoping you could help me with a coding issue.  I have quite a long concatenated formula that is generated via a userform in VBA. The only problem that I have with it is the Textbox6. The value entered by the user should be only 1 or 0 (that’s not the issue). The issue is when the formula is generated, the result relating to Textbox6 is “1=1” or “0=0” followed the rest of the formula. I would like the formula to identify if the Textbox6 has either a 1 or 0 and then apply the condition assigned to that value (something like: Textbox6.Value = 1 Then …). I just can’t seem to get this to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=""BOX ""&IF(OR(Base_Point=1,Base_Point=2,Base_Point=3,Base_Point=4),X_Origin+" & TextBox1 & ",X_Origin-" & TextBox1 & ")&"",""&IF(OR(Base_Point=3,Base_Point=4,Base_Point=5,Base_Point=6),Y_Origin-" & TextBox2 & ",Y_Origin+" & TextBox2 & ")& "",""&IF(" & TextBox6 & "=1,Z_End,Z_Origin)&"" ""&IF(OR(Base_Point=1,Base_Point=2,Base_Point=3,Base_Point=4),X_Origin+" & TextBox3 & ",X_Origin-" & TextBox3 & ")&"",""&IF(OR(Base_Point=3,Base_Point=4,Base_Point=5,Base_Point=6),Y_Origin-" & TextBox4 & ",Y_Origin+" & TextBox4 & ")&"",""&IF(AND(" & TextBox6 & "=1,OR(Base_Point=1,Base_Point=3,Base_Point=5,Base_Point=7)),Z_End-" & TextBox5 & ",IF(AND(" & TextBox6 & "=0,OR(Base_Point=1,Base_Point=3,Base_Point=5,Base_Point=7)),Z_Origin+" & TextBox5 & ",IF(AND(" & TextBox6 & "=1,OR(Base_Point=2,Base_Point=4,Base_Point=6,Base_Point=8)),Z_End+" & TextBox5 & ",IF(AND(" & TextBox6 & "=0,OR(Base_Point=2,Base_Point=4,Base_Point=6,Base_Point=8)),Z_Origin-" & TextBox5 & "))))"
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can try changing the `TextBox6` related parts to `TextBox6.Value`. It should read the value properly. You can also consider changing the control type from `TextBox` to `ComboBox`, if you want to limit user's input.

Comment: I understand what you mean by using TextBox6.Value. I just don’t know the correct way to add it into my code.

Answer (score 0):

According to you comment, does this solution work for you (just replace the `TextBox6` related part of your code)?

```
IIf(TextBox6.Value = 1, "1", "0")
```

You can also evaluate the "0" scenario using nested `IIf` function:

```
IIf(TextBox6.Value = 1, "1", IIf(TextBox6.Value = 0, "0", "NOT_ALLOWED_VALUE"))
```

[How to use IIf function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function)

Comment: Hi Tomasz. Thanks for your answer. It does work as you have written it. However it doesn’t work when inserted into my coding. Hoping someone can help me out with the correct syntax!